# VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to add an image into my GUI, but im having a "VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token" message. I've looked up how to fix it, but I can't figure out how to fix my problem.

Here is the code:

```
frame.setIconImage= (
        new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("tictactoe.gif")).getImage());
```

I am getting the error on the    setIconImage.

I'm doing this on eclipse.

Comment: Is that a method call or an actual field?

Comment: is `setIconImage`  *method* or *variable*?

Comment: Method, but i might be  putting it in the wrong spot, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. @NFE

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need assignment `=` operator. This is used for assign variable value not for method.

Try

```
frame.setIconImage(
        new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("tictactoe.gif")).getImage());
```